# C++ Xcode does not show live issue for external build projects?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, ide

I follow the [instruction](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/preparing/preparing.html) and successfully build and run a C++ project with its Makefile. However I cannot see any live issue while I intentionally making syntax errors.

If I attempt to build files with issues, the issue navigator would display the issues while there is still no live issue pointing out which line occurs this issue.

I have tried the following possible solutions, but none of them works.

1. Turn on the "Show live issue" feature:
   [image]
2. Turn on "Always search user path":
   [image]
3. Delete the derived data in preference-location.

My Xcode live issue feature works fine for other projects(I just use the default target to build). My Xcode version is 8.2.1 and MacOS is 10.12.2.

My question is how to make Xcode show live issue when dealing with external build tools?